# HTML output text does not change based on CSS file in shiny

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I want to change the font size for some htmloutput in a box in shiny. To that purpose I use a CSS external file. One reproducible example would be the following (just change the CSS path):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  includeCSS("C:/.../trial.css"),

  box(width = 4, title = "This does not change", htmlOutput("text")),
  box(width = 4, title = "basic", "Some text that changes")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$text <- renderUI({
      sentence1 <- paste("<h3>", "<b>", "Something", "</b>", "</h3>")
      sentence2 <- paste("<h3>", "<b>", "Something else", "</b>", "</h3>")
      HTML(paste(sentence1, sentence2, sep = "<br/>"))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The CSS file that I am using is specified like this:

```
.box {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 45px;
    color: red;
}
```

My problem is that while in the second box font-size, family and color change, in the first box only the color changes and I cannot figure out why. 
Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `ui` directly in the R console you will see the `ui` HTML structure's, as you can see there is a div called 'shiny-html-output' inside the box div in the first box for that reason CSS reflects in the 2nd box but not in the 1st box.

The below CSS will you get access to the 1st box

```
.box {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 45px;
  color: red;
}
h3 {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 45px;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works, but I have a follow-up. If I understand this correctly, this works because you specified the style for h3 elements, what if I have multiple elements in the box (h1,2,3,...) and I just want to specify the text inside the box?

Comment: Probably something like `h3, h2, h1 {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 45px;
  color: red;
}` or would there be a better alternative?

Comment: @User2321 I use h3 as CSS selector as you define "Something" and "Something else" inside an h3 tag, so you end up with a div "h3" inside another div "box". If you have normal text  inside the box then your default CSS will trigger. Try open in browser after you run the App then use Devlopers tool to navigate through your UI.

Comment: @User2321, Yes if you have multiple headers

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!